# SensorEvent.timestamp to absolute (utc) timestamp?

Tags: android

I question myself what the timestamp in SensorEvent.timestamp means. Numbers like 3548712982000 occur. It is not plausible for anything: nanoseconds/milliseconds since 1970 etc. Is this maybe some overflow error? It seems as it is different on different devices at the same time!!!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just a few seconds after this question on SO I found the answer:

[See comment #18 of this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36916900#comment18) where it's said that these are nanoseconds since boot (`SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()`).

The android documentation definitively needs an update. [The doc issue has been recently reported again](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67759334), feel free to star it.

Comment: This isn't wholly accurate unfortunately, as sensor events can sometimes get backlogged and be received 2 or 3 seconds after its initial creation time. This would mess up the arithmetic. Perhaps there's a way to find the time at which the system booted: i.e. the relative epoch. At the very least, it could be calculated by the current time minus `SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()`