# Accelerometer SensorEvent timestamp

Tags: android

Im currently working on a android application.. I have to log the accelerometer sensor event coordinate with event time. I got the sensor event timestamp like "3497855005850" but i am not able to convert event timestamp into user readable date time format.Thanks in advance

How can i convert SensorEvent timestamp to unix timestamp?

Comment: ugh!! another industry standard :) . indeed naming is toughest problem in computer industry. I fell in same trap.

Answer (score 41):

The sensor timestamp is actually nanoseconds of uptime, **not** system time in nanoseconds. See [SensorEvent.timestamp to absolute (utc) timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498006/sensorevent-timestamp-to-absolute-utc-timestamp).

In theory, you can convert sensor timestamp to time in milliseconds using:

```
long timeInMillis = (new Date()).getTime() 
                    + (sensorEvent.timestamp - System.nanoTime()) / 1000000L;
```

You could even bracket the `(new Date()).getTime()` call with two `System.nanoTime()` calls and average them to get closer to the actual offset.

Then you can format the sensor time as date and time.

Comment: As of Android 4.2.1 (API lvl 17), on my Nexus 4, the `sensorEvent.timestamp` seems to contains the exact timestamp (in nanoseconds). This seems to be undocumented, despite it is very important!

Comment: I can vouch for what Romain says.

Comment: It seems the timestamp's value is unfortunately not depending on Android's version: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56561

Comment: For a SensorEvent of type STEP_COUNTER, this doesn't work for Samsung S4 with Android 5 - so basically the answer given isn't really that much use or correct for that sensor type. I initially thought that the answer  of Boban S made sense but that doesn't actually work either for this type of sensor on this device. Essentially you have the time the event is raised for that type of sensor - presumably because it is an aggregate of events and not a single one.

Comment: I'm curious: 1. could we use `System.currentTimeMillis()` instead of `(new Date()).getTime()`? 2. what's the difference between `sensorEvent.timestamp` and `System.nanoTime()`? It's said that they both are nano-seconds of uptime since last boot

Comment: It seems the references (begin time since) of `sensorEvent.timestamp` and `System.nanoTime()` are different on my device (Galaxy S7).

Comment: This is an incorrect answer. The sensor timestamps could be not in nanoseconds of uptime, it differs from manufacturer to manufacturer.

Answer (score 5):

You can set referent time variables in your `onSensorChanged(SensorEvent)` function.
Reference for current time and event time. When event arrives subtract sensor referent time from event time and you will have difference in nanoseconds. You can add that difference divided by 1,000,000 to current time reference to get event time in milliseconds.
Error with calculating this can be max 0.5 milliseconds for one event. You can minimize error by changing referent times occasionally.

```
private long sensorTimeReference = 0l;
private long myTimeReference = 0l;

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // set reference times
    if(sensorTimeReference == 0l && myTimeReference == 0l) {
        sensorTimeReference = event.timestamp;
        myTimeReference = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    // set event timestamp to current time in milliseconds
    event.timestamp = myTimeReference + 
        Math.round((event.timestamp - sensorTimeReference) / 1000000.0);
    // some code...
}
```

Comment: how do you deal with sensors that have latency in reporting their values?

Answer (score 4):

https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/hal-interface.html#sensors_event_t
"timestamp must be synchronized with the elapsedRealtimeNano clock" 
so

```
val timeInMills = System.currentTimeMillis() + (event.timestamp - SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()) / 1000000
```

Comment: the correct answer is this one, otherwise the timestamp will be shifted

Comment: @chejdj
Why are we adding `(event.timestamp - SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos())` to the `System.currentTimeMillis()`? Doesn't it put the actual event time ahead of the current time?

Comment: Also, I could not understand why are we adding `nanos` to the `millis`?

Comment: The base of the `SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()` and `SensorEvent.timestamp` can be different (relative since boot) than the base of the `System.currentTimeMillis()` (wall clock time). Should it still work?

Comment: Even though it works (or does not), could someone please explain why and how it works?

Comment: @SagarPatel  sensor_event  timestamp and elapsedRealtimenanos are the same base time 'boot time'

Comment: so event.timestamp-elapsedRealtime should be < 0 (b/c there will be delay when your code gets to it in OnSensorChanged, you basically calculated that delay here), thus currentTime + that gives you "wall" clock time of the event. kinda makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

The official `SensorEvent#timestamp` [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent#timestamp) states:

> [event.time is] The time in nanoseconds at which the event happened. For a given sensor, **each new sensor event should be** monotonically increasing **using the same time base as SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()**.

**Challenge**

- **Some manufacturers/devices** use the `SystemClock.currentTimeNanos()` instead (e.g. Nexus 4).

**Device-independent solution:**

```
/**
 * Calculates the static offset (ms) which needs to
 *  be added to the `event.time` (ns) to get the Unix
 *  timestamp of the event.
 *
 * @param eventTimeNanos the {@code SensorEvent.time} to be used to determine the time offset
 * @return the offset in milliseconds
 */
private long eventTimeOffset(final long eventTimeNanos) {
    // Capture timestamps of event reporting time
    final long elapsedRealTimeMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    final long upTimeMillis = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    final long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // Check which timestamp the event.time is closest to the event.time
    final long eventTimeMillis = eventTimeNanos / 1_000_000L;
    final long elapsedTimeDiff = elapsedRealTimeMillis - eventTimeMillis;
    final long upTimeDiff = upTimeMillis - eventTimeMillis;
    final long currentTimeDiff = currentTimeMillis - eventTimeMillis;

    // Default case (elapsedRealTime, following the documentation)
    if (Math.abs(elapsedTimeDiff) <= Math.min(Math.abs(upTimeDiff), Math.abs(currentTimeDiff))) {
        final long bootTimeMillis = currentTimeMillis - elapsedRealTimeMillis;
        return bootTimeMillis;
    }

    // Other seen case (currentTime, e.g. Nexus 4)
    if (Math.abs(currentTimeDiff) <= Math.abs(upTimeDiff)) {
        return 0;
    }

    // Possible case, but unknown if actually used by manufacturers (upTime)
    throw new IllegalStateException("The event.time seems to be upTime. In this case we cannot use a static offset to calculate the Unix timestamp of the event");
}
```

---

Registration time delay

- This code is independent of the latency between the `event.time` and the time at which the sensor event listener is triggered (registration time) as we only use the `SystemClock` to calculate the offset.
- This allows to synchronize the sensor data between multiple devices if their system time is synchronized (there are apps for this).

---

*Regarding "Possible Case" (see code):*

- It's unknown if any manufacturer actually uses the `upTime` as `event.time`. Thus, we throw an exception to see if this actually ever happens.
- If this happens and if we calculate a static offset between `currentTime` and `upTime` this would lead to time  shifts when the device is in (deep) sleep again. We would need to calculate the offset dynamically for each event which is quite heavy.
- If this happens on devices this could be tested using: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#testing_doze_and_app_standby

Comment: By far, this is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and used ehartwell's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9333605/5320080). However I used `System.currentTimeMillis()` instead of `new Date().getTime()`.

Furthermore I found that there is an offset of `sensorEvent.timeStamp` and `System.nanoTime()` of maximal 300 ms, mostly < 200 ms. Depending on the needed accuracy you can ignore this difference.

If I use Boban S. [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18979003/5320080), the difference is correct at the initialisation. However, the correct time and the time of the measurements diverge. The estimated time of the measurements is in the future.

Comment: Over what time frame is the divergence occurring, and by how much?  Are you seeing this across multiple devices?

Answer (score 1):

I see three ways to get millis (Kotlin)

```
val millis = Date().getTime() + (event.timestamp - System.nanoTime()) / 1000000L

val millis = System.currentTimeMillis() + (event.timestamp - System.nanoTime()) / 1000000L

val millis = System.currentTimeMillis() + (event.timestamp - SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()) / 1000000L
```

all three deliver same result, but when I want to see diff from calculated value to current time

```
val diff  = System.currentTimeMillis() - millis
```

I see 'diff' with value **-359704905** ?

```
Log.d("diff", "" + event.timestamp + " - " + System.nanoTime())
```

> diff: 541695268300000 - 181990403666592
>
> diff: 541695277240000 - 181990405818592
>
> diff: 541695286859000 - 181990411901592
>
> diff: 541695296139000 - 181990412584592
>
> diff: 541695305735000 - 181990415222592

So all suggested solution **are not right**

for me this simple way fits my needs

```
override fun onSensorChanged(sensorEvent: SensorEvent?) {
    val millis = System.currentTimeMillis()
}
```

Comment: This solution does not work if you have set any latency at registration time*. With latency>0, you will have a number of readings arriving at the same time and you will assign the same time stamp to all of them. 
* registration using 
public boolean registerListener(SensorEventListener listener, Sensor sensor,
            int samplingPeriodUs, int maxReportLatencyUs)

Answer (score 1):

It varies for each device. It could be based on epoch, time since boot, and CPU awake time. Best approach is to read all three, then see which one the timestamp is closest to, then convert based on the offset.

Answer (score 1):

`SensorEvent.timestamp` is when the event happened, but it is an elapsed time since boot. It is not the time when the event happened. We want to get the actual time when the event happened from the elapsed time since the event happened.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent#timestamp

1. We need all the entities in a similar unit. We are taking `Millis` here.
2. We have three entities to use. a) `System.currentTimeMillis()` b) `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` and c) `SensorEvent.timestamp`

[image]

3. If we use `SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()`, then we need to convert it into `Millis` as below:

```
val systemCurrentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
val systemClockElapsedRealtimeMillis = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos())
val sensorEventTimeStampMillis = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(sensorEvent.timestamp)
```

4. We need to find the difference between the `systemCurrentTimeMillis`, and `systemClockElapsedRealtimeMillis` as below:

[image]

```
val currentMinusElapsedRealtimeMillis = systemCurrentTimeMillis - systemClockElapsedRealtimeMillis
```

5. Once we find the difference, we need to add `sensorEventTimeStampMillis` to it as below:

[image]
OR
[image]

```
val actualEventTimeMillis = currentMinusElapsedRealtimeMillis + sensorEventTimeStampMillis
```

6. Then, we need to convert the result into UTC as below (I am using `Joda Time`):

```
val actualEventTimeUtc = DateTime(actualEventTimeMillis, DateTimeZone.UTC)
```

The `actualEventTimeUtc` is the absolute time when the event happened.

**Another way to understand it is:**

Suppose the sensor reports an event in `onSensorChanged.` We find that the current time is: 13 PM. In other words, the reporting time is 13 PM and it is not the time when the actual event happened.

The `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` says that it has been running since last 30 hours. In other words, it started 30 hours before from the current time.

So, we subtract the 30 hours from the current time to get the time when the sensor started. So, we get 7 AM of the previous day.

The `SensorEvent.timestamp` says that the event happened after 28 hours of the `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime().`

Hence, we add 28 hours to the 7 AM of the previous day. So, we get 11 AM of the current day and it is the actual time when event happened.