# GraphView shows wrong graph in real time mode when scrollToEnd is true

Tags: android, graph, android-graphview

I'm sampling accelerometer sensor and present a graph in real time, using [`Graph View`](http://www.android-graphview.org/) library (4.0.1).

The app is working well except the graph is wrong:

[image]

As you can see in the picture, Z axis (magenta color) has value of ~9.8 but in the graph it's shows as ~15, Y axis (green color) has value of 0.2 but in the graph us under the zero and same idea with X axis.

Here is my code:

```
SensorManager sensorManager;
TextView tvX, tvY, tvZ;
GraphView graph;
LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> seriesX, seriesY, seriesZ;
long startTime;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_runtime_graph);

    tvX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAcc_X);    // color : blue
    tvY = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAcc_Y);    // color : green
    tvZ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAcc_Z);    // color : magenta
    graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);

    seriesX = new LineGraphSeries<>();
    seriesY = new LineGraphSeries<>();
    seriesZ = new LineGraphSeries<>();

    seriesX.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    seriesY.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    seriesZ.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);

    graph.addSeries(seriesX);
    graph.addSeries(seriesY);
    graph.addSeries(seriesZ);

    startTime = System.nanoTime() / 100000000;

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
{
    tvX.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[0]));
    tvY.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[1]));
    tvZ.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[2]));

    updateGraph((event.timestamp / 100000000) - startTime,
            event.values[0], event.values[1], event.values[2]);
}

void updateGraph (final long timestamp, final float x, final float y, final float z)
{
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            seriesX.appendData(new DataPoint(timestamp, x), true, 40);
            seriesY.appendData(new DataPoint(timestamp, y), true, 40);
            seriesZ.appendData(new DataPoint(timestamp, z), true, 40);
        }
    });
}
```

I found the issue happened when `scrollToEnd` field is set to `true`, otherwise the graph is right. Another issue I found that may be related, the axis are not update when `scro;lToEnd` is true.

How can I beat the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

logcat shows why scrollToEnd does not work in your case:

```
GraphView: scrollToEnd works only with manual x axis bounds
```

to set the x axis bounds manual, add this code in your create method

```
Viewport vp = graph.getViewport();
vp.setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
vp.setMinX(0);
vp.setMaxX(1000);
```

but there is another issue with the code:
**System.nanoTime()** and **event.timestamp** are different time formats

```
System.nanoTime() // current value of system timer in nanoseconds
event.timestamp // nanoseconds since device uptime
```

This is not very well documented: [SensorEvent timestamp](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7981)

See also: [Accelerometer SensorEvent timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500765/accelerometer-sensorevent-timestamp?lq=1)

Comment: Thanks frank to your answer. About the `timestamp` you're really right; about the `bounds` - this is exactly the problem. I'm not want to limit\define the min and max axis value because it's change from sensor to sensor (it's can be from 0 to 2 for one sensor and for another sensor from 0 to 1400). So, maybe the question should be how to update the Axis too

Comment: Do you need it dynamic for both axis? If you only set the XAxisBounds to manual, the Y axis will still scale automatically.

Comment: Yes, I need the both axis to be dynamic (I'm sample sensors in my app so one axis is to values and the second is the timestamp) but I'll try to limit X axis according sensor.max value. Thank you very much!

Comment: seems like there is no way to update the axis and I must to define them in order to show run time graph. Thank you!