# How to convert nanoseconds of uptime into a readable date time format

Tags: java, android, python

I have extracted accerometer data from a android wearable. While looking at the data i realised the timestamp is not unix covertable. After research i saw the timestamp was actually nanoseconds in uptime. My question is the same as [Accelerometer SensorEvent timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500765/accelerometer-sensorevent-timestamp). However due to me not knowing Java i dont know how convert it using the solutions provided. Is there any python ways i can convert the nanoseconds in uptime into a readable date time format? An example of the timestamp would be "45900482044637".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
Duration.ofNanos ( 45_900_482_044_637L )
```

> PT12H45M0.482044637S

## java.time

Java 8 and later has a [`Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class for this purpose, as part of the new [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework (see [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html)). These new classes have [nanosecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) resolution (nine decimal places in fractional second). A [`Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) represents a span of time as a number of hours, minutes, and seconds.

Android currently does not use Java 8 technology, but there is a [back-port of java.time](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) to Java 6 & 7. Further adapted to Android in the *ThreeTenABP* project.

Note the `L` appended to numeric literal for a `long`. Also, underscores make lengthy numbers easier for humans to decipher.

```
long input = 45_900_482_044_637L;
```

Let's convert that number to a `Duration` object.

```
Duration duration = Duration.ofNanos ( input );
```

When we generate a String representation of that `Duration` object, we get a String formatted using the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) standard. That standard uses the pattern `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` where the `P` marks the beginning  and the `T` separates years-months-days from the hours-minutes-seconds.

```
    System.out.println ( "duration: " + duration );
```

The answer is twelve hours, forty-five minutes, and a fraction of a second.

> duration: PT12H45M0.482044637S

---

[image: Table of span-of-time classes in Java and in the ThreeTen-Extra project]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

To get the uptime in human-readable format in Python:

```py
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> ns = 45900482044637
>>> print(timedelta(microseconds=round(ns, -3) // 1000))
12:45:00.482045
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
long millis = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(nanosecond, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
Date date = new Date(millis );
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm aaa");
String dateFormatted = formatter.format(date);
```

Comment: I don't think OP wants January 1, 1970 date.