# How can I get the time of Android Sensor data for Realtime plot?

Tags: android, android-sensors, android-graphview

I am trying to plot the data of Light sensor from my Android smartphone using GraphView library. For the Data points' x-axis value I need the time at which the sensor gives its reading. What is the best way to get the most accurate sensor event time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accelerometer SensorEvent timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500765/accelerometer-sensorevent-timestamp)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            event.timestamp // is the timestamp of event occurence

    }
```

`event.timestamp` is in nanosecons not miliseconds so be careful

[Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sensorEvent.timestamp`
You will get the time in nanoseconds.

So, you can use this -

```
(System.nanoTime() - sensorEvent.timestamp)/Math.pow(10,6)
```

to log the time in milliseconds!

Comment: I tried 

(System.nanoTime() - sensorEvent.timestamp)/1000000000L;

to get time in seconds but it gives me negative numbers having 6 digits.